# Disabling the checkbox if the value is zero in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am Inserting the checkbox value as 0 and 1 if the checkbox is checked the value will be inserted as 1 else it will be inserted as zero.While fetching he records getting he checkbox as checked if the value is 1 .If the value is zero the checkbox should be displayed while displaying.

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $r->blog_id;?>" class="test"
                        <?php if ($r->featured_blogs == 1) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> ></td>
```

As of now it is displaying only the checkboxes checked it is not disabling the unchecked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample working code for you. Instead of `if`, you should use `ternary` operator:

```
<?php
$r->blog_id = 1;
$r->featured_blogs = 1;
?>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $r->blog_id;?>" class="test" <?php echo ($r->featured_blogs == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> ></td>
```

Comment: Above code is a working example. Did you checked the values of `featured_blog` and `blog_id`? You can check here https://3v4l.org/tbv6b

Comment: blog_id is a primary key in database and featured blog will be inserted as 0 and 1